# Gmaps Dutch postalcode to address issue

Tags: google-maps

im working with gmaps to get an adrress by postalcode,
the only problem is that there can be multiple streets on 1 postalcode.
i've tried to send the housenumber with the address parameter but i couldn't figure out how.

for example:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=5144AC&sensor=false
```

i get a good output but if a add a number like this:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=5144AC 1&sensor=false
```

it doen't work.

who can help me.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to url encode all the parameters:

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=5144AC%201&sensor=false

So, instead of a space, use %20

See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: As far as I can tell, Google api doesn't support postal code lookup with house number.